# how to get server response time by Java

Tags: java, server-timing

I would like  to get Server-Timing information by Java as in mentioned here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Server-Timing

Mainly I would like to get information about how long it took from to get a response. I want to get it from the browser. Not by adding my own time calculation from the client-side.Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use JMeter, an apache tool that helps with load testing could be of help

Comment: is there any Java API to get it from the used browser?

Comment: Yes it has an API, you may learn about it